# Missed ground connection

Tags: transit, refunds

I missed my connection to Rome in Frankfurt because of a long line in customs. Lufthansa put me on another flight which made me late by 2 hours and my prepaid connection to the port had, of course, left. So, under pressure for time to catch the boat I had to take a taxi which cost 180,00 Euros or 266.70 Cad. Is this collectable from any source?

Comment: Sadly, a long customs line is neither the fault of the airline nor the airport, but of the government of the country you were clearing customs in (Germany) not having sufficient agents for the demand. Other than travel insurance, you're out of luck as I can't see the german government paying up!

Answer (score 5):

Your best option for recovering this expense is probably your travel insurance. It likely covers extra expenses incurred due to late or delayed transportation (particularly if you had pre-arranged transportation that you missed).

Comment: Tried that and after looking through the policy they think there isn't any coverage. I filed a complaint anyway but not expecting anything.

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine missed an expensive train connection within Germany after a 3-hour delay of the Helsinki-Munich flight. He contacted Lufthansa and complained about the situation, he got full compensation for the train tickets as well as a generous voucher that he can use the next time he's booking a Lufthansa ticket.

Long story short, contacting Lufthansa and telling about the situation in detail is your best bet. Send a copy of the receipts for any pre-booked connection or the taxi if available.

Comment: Probably worth a short (+1) but unfortunately for the OP, a 3-hour delay is very different from a 2-hour delay under [EU “Air passenger rights” rules](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm). And it seems the flights themselves weren't even late.

Comment: Lufthansa have already done everything that could be expected of them: they got the asker to her destination without any delays that were their fault. One can always try asking them for compensation but don't expect much: if they're feeling generous, they might give some coupons.